# Is Angular Momentum truly fundamental?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

This may seem like a slightly trite question, but it is one that has long intrigued me.

Since I formally learned classical (Newtonian) mechanics, it has often struck me that angular momentum (and generally rotational dynamics) can be fully derived from normal (linear) momentum and dynamics. Simply by considering circular motion of a point mass and introducing new quantities, it seems one can describe and explain angular momentum fully without any new postulates. In this sense, I am lead to believe only ordinary momentum and dynamics are fundamental to mechanics, with rotational stuff effectively being a corollary.

Then at a later point I learned quantum mechanics. Alright, so orbital angular momentum does not really disturb my picture of the origin/fundamentality, but when we consider the concept of *spin*, this introduces a problem in this proposed (philosophical) understanding. Spin is apparently intrinsic angular momentum; that is, it applies to a point particle. Something can possess angular momentum that is not actually moving/rotating - a concept that does not exist in classical mechanics! Does this imply that angular momentum is in fact a fundamental quantity, intrinsic to the universe in some sense?

It somewhat bothers me that that fundamental particles such as electrons and quarks can possess their own angular momentum (spin), when otherwise angular momentum/rotational dynamics would fall out quite naturally from normal (linear) mechanics. There are of course some fringe theories that propose that even these so-called fundamental particles are composite, but at the moment physicists widely accept the concept of intrinsic angular momentum. In any case, can this dilemma be resolved, or do we simply have to extend our framework of fundamental quantities?

Comment: http://abstrusegoose.com/342

Answer (score 56):

**Note** As David pointed out, it's better to distinguish between generic *angular momentum* and *orbital angular momentum*. The first concept is more general and includes spin while the second one is (as the name suggests) just about orbiting. There is also the concept of *total angular momentum* which is the quantity that is really conserved in systems with rotational symmetry. But in the absence of spin it coincides with *orbital angular momentum*. This is the situation I analyze in the first paragraph.

---

Angular momentum **is** fundamental. Why? [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) tells us that the symmetry of the system (in this case space-time) leads to the conservation of some quantity (momentum for translation, orbital angular momentum for rotation). Now, as it happens, Euclidean space is both translation and rotation invariant in compatible manner, so these concepts are related and it can appear that you can derive one from the other. But there might exist space-time that is translation but not rotation invariant and vice versa. In such a space-time you wouldn't get a relation between orbital angular momentum and momentum.

Now, to address the spin. Again, it is a result of some symmetry. But in this case the symmetry arises because of [Wigner's correspondence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_classification) between particles and irreducible representations of the [Poincaré group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincare_group) which is the symmetry group of the [Minkowski space-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space). This correspondence tells us that massive particles are classified by their mass and spin. But spin is not orbital angular momentum! The spin corresponds to group $Spin(3) \cong SU(2)$ which is a double cover of $SO(3)$ (rotational symmetry of three-dimensional Euclidean space). So this is a completely different concept that is only superficially similar and can't really be directly compared with orbital angular momentum. One way to see this is that spin can be a half-integer, but orbital angular momentum must always be an integer.

So to summarize:

- *orbital angular momentum* is a classical concept that arises in any space-time with rotational symmetry.
- *spin* is a concept that comes from quantum field theory built on the Minkowski space-time. The same concept also works for classical field theory, but there we don't have a clear correspondence with particles, so I omitted this case.

---

**Addition for the curious**

As Eric has pointed out, there is more than just a superficial similarity between orbital angular momentum and spin. To illustrate the connection, it's useful to consider the question of how particle's properties transform under the change of coordinates (recall that conservation of total angular momentum arises because of the invariance to the change of coordinates that corresponds to rotation). Let us proceed in a little bit more generality and consider any transformation $\Lambda$ from the Lorentz group. Let us have a field $V^a(x^{\mu})$ that transforms in matrix representation ${S^a}_b (\Lambda)$ of the Lorentz group. Thanks to Wigner we know this corresponds to some particle; e.g. it could be scalar (like Higgs), bispinor (like electron) or vector (like Z boson). Its transformation properties under the element ${\Lambda^{\mu}}_{\nu}$ are then determined by (using Einstein summation convention)

$$ V'^a ({\Lambda^{\mu}}_{\nu} x^{\nu}) = {S^a}_b(\Lambda) V^b (x^{\mu}) $$

From this one can at least intuitively see the relation between the properties of the space-time ($\Lambda$) and the particle ($S$). To return to the original question: $\Lambda$ contains information about the orbital angular momentum and $S$ contains information about the spin. So the two are connected but not in a trivial way. In particular, I don't think it's very useful to imagine spin as the actual *spinning* of the particle (contrary to the terminology). But of course anyone is free to imagine whatever they feel helps them grasp the theory better.

Comment: The second statement is not really correct. Spin is a natural concept for nonrelativistic QM. Moreover, spin variables is not a good way to classify the representations of Poincare, the correct way is to use helicity and total angular momentum.

Comment: Interesting. I am aware of Noether's theorem, but I thought it indicates that rotational symmetry of space-time corresponds to conservation of angular momentum, which somewhat begs the very idea.

Comment: @Grisha: spin is **not** natural in QM. It is inserted by hand. If you want to understand its origin, you have to study QFT (or at least Dirac equation). As for the latter part: I am talking about **massive** particles. There is really no need to talk about helicity there. You only need it for **massless** particles.

Comment: Excellent summary.  One thing to add is that the two concepts are related in that they both pertain to quantities conserved by a particle/system in its rest frame (i.e. the group fixing some point) -- a bit more than "superficially similar," I'd say.

Comment: @Eric: right, there are similarities. I should probably also mention something about total angular momentum.

Comment: I'd disagree with the statement that spin is not angular momentum. It certainly acts like angular momentum in some sense. But it is distinct from _orbital_ angular momentum (if "angular momentum" in your answer was replaced with "orbital angular momentum" I would have no complaints :-P)

Comment: @David: you are of course correct and I am going to fix this immediately. Still, I guess people probably understood what I meant.

Comment: @Marek. There are Poisson brackets for the angular momentum in classical mechanics. If you use Heisenberg's canonical quantization, you obtain the algebra of the angular momentum operators. Only from this algebra you can easily show that 2j+1 should be an integer number, where "j" is the maximal projection of the momentum. Therefore, "j" can be either integer or half-integer. Of course, it is because Lie algebra accounts for local properties of a group which is the same for SO(3) and SU(2). It is a simple QM, where is no Poincare.

Comment: Moreover, if you use the method of induced representations to construct the representations of Poincare, then, of course, the little group (aka stabilizer subgroup) would be SU(2) for a massive state. But this little group classifies the total angular momentum of the state in the rest frame. In QFT you can not construct operator only for the spin for any state - it exists only for the total angular momentum. Consider a Dirac particle in the Coulomb field, there aren't states with a definite electron spin - just because it is not conserved. Spin is an essentially nonrelativistic concept.

Comment: What happens if we remove the symmetries of the metric tensor (eg. isotropy) by going to curved spacetimes (GR)?

Comment: @Grisha: We were talking about the **spin** being or not being natural in QM, not about the orbital angular momentum. Of course, orbital angular momentum is natural in quantum mechanics (essentially because it comes from quantization of the corresponding classical concept). But there is no classical concept of spin for particles. Only for fields. And to get any sensible meaning for the statement "particles carry spin" you have to quantize the field and make the particle approximation. This is the **only** natural way of introducing spin for particles.

Comment: @Grisha: just to clarify: when you are talking about spin, do you mean a spin operator? Because I was talking about the spin as a quantum number (e.g. electron having spin one half) and this is definitely a relativistic concept.

Comment: @mtrencseni: then you are only left with local properties because locally every space-time looks like Minkowski space-time (i.e. locally it's still true that momentum and angular momentum will be conserved). But globally you can no longer say anything about momentum or angular momentum, unless your space-time has some (very special) symmetry.

Comment: @Marek: My question was directed at spin. You wrote: "Again, it is a result of some symmetry. But in this case the symmetry arises because of Wigner's correspondence between particles and irreducible representations of the Poincaré group which is the symmetry group of the Minkowski space-time." So, if we take away the appropriate (global) symmetry of the metric, can we still define spin? Or is the fact that it is everywhere locally Minkowski enough? Thanks!

Comment: @mtrencseni: I see. A very good question indeed! I wasn't being precise. When one says *symmetry of the space-time*, what is really being implied is the symmetry of the **physical laws** (I will update my answer to reflect this), while the space-time is only chosen to respect this (i.e. you get Euclidean space + time for Newtonian mechanics and Minkowski space-time for Special Theory of Relativity). Now, the equations of motion are always local in modern physics (because we dislike action at a distance), so the concept of spin indeed works the same way on the curved background.

Comment: @Marek. It seems you skip my arguments finished by the phrase "Therefore, j can be either integer or half-integer", where I said nothing about orbital momentum. I was talking about the operator, because you mentioned the representations of Poincare. The physical way to classify representations is to choose operators which are separately commute with the Hamiltonian. There is no such operator as "spin". You can check the explicit form of spherical bispinor (Landau&Lifshitz Vol.4 Eq.(24.13)) - they mix different projections of spin and orbital momentum - only total angular momentum is definite.

Comment: @Grisha: I didn't skip it, but instead misread it. Now I have to disagree with you. You start by talking about quantization of the classical angular momentum (which, by the way, is **orbital** angular momentum) but then you proceed to talk about half-integer spins, so you dropped commutation relations of $\bf x$ and $\bf L$ somewhere along the way (which is what enforces integer spins). Now, what you say after that is really just that spin is **consistent** with QM. But this neither proves that spin it's **natural** (which it can't because it isn't) nor does it explain its origin.

Comment: @Grisha: right. I can also see that you know what you are talking about and I see what you are aiming at, but we are simply not able to communicate our points clearly (and this small comment box isn't a best medium for this anyway). Also, probably we have a different view on what counts as *natural*. In any case, thank you for the conversation!

Comment: I was not taking about orbital momentum, I was talking about the operators of total angular momentum, which are generators of the group of rotations. I didn't drop commutation relations with x because com. relations of the total angular momentum with any vector/tensor operator are fixed by the transformation rules for this operator. And nothing enforces interger values of total  angular momentum in QM. But you are right this small box is very inconvenient espessaly if you use phone ;) Thnx for discussion.

Comment: Wouldn't bodies in angular motion also have some orbital motion just by virtue of trying to achieve equilibrium?

Comment: @conqenator: I am not sure what you mean. I was talking about classical point particle orbiting around something, so there is really only one kind of motion there. Are you perhaps thinking about rigid body that both rotates itself and is also orbiting (like Earth rotating around its axis and also around Sun)?

Comment: Spin is natural in quantum mechanics. QFT only incorporate the spin inside the observables that construct the hamiltonian. Dirac equation in any way revels the nature of the spin, only encode the spin in a more fashion way (spinor field). Actually spins arise when we are interested in irreducible representations of rotational symmetry, namely, particle states with rotational symmetry. See Weinberg QFT volume 1.

Answer (score 28):

In the field of classical mechanics, angular momentum is almost always derived from linear momentum. This actually might be the problem, because it is also possible to do it the other way around: linear momentum is a limiting case of angular momentum where the radius of rotation becomes infinite. In this view the split between rotational and linear *vanishes* - the new concept that is introduced is: *infinity*.

This is not a new idea of mine, it has been established since the 19th century. By using projective geometry, one can integrate linear and angular kinematics and dynamics in one framework (i.e. a translation is a rotation around an infinite axis; a pure moment is a force along an infinite line of action). Keywords: Felix Klein, linear complexes.

Another issue is intrinsic angular momentum. I could say: study the fundamentals, the principles, and the maths, and eventually you'll get a holistic picture, but that's not what I believe. I think we are in need of some kind of *geometrical* electron model that permits us to depict intrinsic angular momentum.

Comment: Interesting thoughts there, I agree we're in need of a more geometrical model. May have a look at that framework you mention.

Comment: Do you have some references for seeing linear momentum as a limiting case of angular momentum via projective geometry?

Comment: I googeld and saw that a book of Portmann/Wallner is online: http://alas.matf.bg.ac.rs/~vsrdjan/files/pottman.pdf. Part 3.4.

Comment: Basically a translation can be seen as a rotation around a line at infinity at 0 degrees. Likewise a pure moment (i.e. zero net force) can be seen as force of 0 along a line at infinity.

Answer (score 21):

whether you call a similar concept "fundamental" is a matter of taste - and the proposition is just a meaningless emotional slogan. The angular momentum is surely an important quantity that is, in a very well-defined sense, as important as the normal momentum. Incidentally, both of them are conserved if the physical laws are symmetric with respect to translations and rotations, respectively.

So the real question is why the spin in quantum mechanics can't be reduced to the orbital motion - i.e. to the "linear motion" and ordinary "momentum". It's because the objects in quantum mechanics are described not just by their shape in space but by wave functions, and wave functions may be said to transform nontrivially (into something else) under rotations.

In particular, if the wave function (or a field) is a vector or a tensor or, most typically, a spinor, then it means that in a different coordinate system, the values of the components of the wave function will be different. This is possible even in the case when the wave function (or field) is fully localized at one point, i.e. nothing is rotating "orbitally".

The angular momentum is defined by the change of the phase of the wave function under rotations, which may come from the dependence of the wave function on space, but also from the transformations of the components of the wave function among each other, which is possible even if everything is localized at a point. So even point-like objects may carry an angular momentum in quantum mechanics, the spin.

Note that the spin is a multiple of $\hbar/2$ and $\hbar$ is sent to zero in the classical limit, so in the classical limit, the spin as the internal angular momentum becomes zero and disappears, anyway.

Another new feature of the spin is that unlike the angular momentum, it may be half-integer, not just a multiple of $\hbar$: also $\hbar/2$ is possible. That's because the wave functions (and fields) may transform as spinors that change the sign if they're rotated by 360 degrees. Only a rotation by 720 degrees is topologically indistinguishable from "no rotation", so wave functions are obliged to return to their original values under a 720 degree rotation. But fermions change their signs under rotations by 360 degrees which corresponds to their half-integral spin.

If the word "fundamental" means that it can't be reduced to some other things such as a classical intuition about motion and rotation, then be sure that the spin is damn fundamental, much like the rest of quantum mechanics.

Best wishes
Lubos

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think your reasoning is right. Physicists like to use the term "fundamental" a lot, but it probably isn't very well-defined.

Comment: Dear Noldorin, I actually use it often, too - but just not for random quantities such as the angular momentum. I use it for important principles and universal laws - anything that is not just an approximation; anything that is unique and doesn't have lots of "sibling concepts"; anything that matters in the whole Universe. In particular, the fundamental scale is probably the Planck scale - more generally, it's the place where the most accurate, not approximate laws of the Universe show their physical consequences directly.

Comment: Fundamental means axiomatical.

Answer (score 6):

In classical mechanics, the fundamental entities change according to the framework you opt for. If you do classical Newtonian mechanics, I'd say the fundamental entities are postions and velocities. All the others can be derived from them and the dynamics of particles are described in terms of functions of these (forces are functions of time, positions and velocities).

But if you go to Hamiltonian mechanics, then positions and momenta become fundamental. And the Hamiltonian can be expressed as a function of these and possibly time.

Clearly, in classical mechanics, angular momentum is always a derived quantity, because it is always an orbital angular momentum, never an intrinsic angular momentum. Even when you have an object rotating on an own axis, this can be understood as the particles constituting the object executing an orbital motion. Of course, you can write Hamiltonians which depend on the angular momentum of the top, but these are higher level descriptions, the angular momentum of the top could still be decomposed in principle into the orbital angular momenta of its constituents. This would not be a very practical approach to problem-solving of course.

Therefore, as you say, a fundamental intrinsic angular momentum is a novelty in quantum mechanics. The way it enters the equations is usually through the multiple-valuedness of the wave function. Say a spin 1/2 particle has to be described by two independent component wave functions (there could be more components, but these would not be independent). I don't know of any way around this. This is a basic fact of how nature works and it is related to the representations of the symmetry group of space-time.

Since the symmetry group of space-time is basically the same in quantum and in classical physics, I don't see however why it should not be possible to describe particles with intrinsic momenta in classical mechanics. I think it is certainly possible in principle. The question is, is it useful? Since all our elementary particles have to be described at the quantum level, what use is a classical theory of particles with intrinsic momenta? Except in the sense of tackling problems like the top by simplification or something?

EDIT: As a matter of fact, classical field theories do have spin. Think of the Maxwell equations for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It confirms a few of my views for sure. I wasn't aware classical field theories predict spin. Ordinary quantum mechanics is not a field theory and predicts spin, however?

Comment: @Noldorin: it doesn't predict it. You can work in QM without spin as well. Also, in QM mechanics you can have spin 1/2 bosons, which isn't really consistent with reality. That is why Dirac equation was such a huge success: it indeed did predict spin! But it wasn't until later that people understood where spin is really coming from. For that you need to consider fields.

Comment: @Raskolnikov: classical field theory and quantum particles are deeply related. The bridge is through quantum field theory. This is obtained by quantization of classical field theory. Once you have it quantized, you can notice that there exists something called "particle approximation" (this is about Feynman diagrams). So in the end you'll arrive at particles. So it's morally correct to say their spin comes from classical field theory.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Marek; that makes a bit more sense. (Also, I don't think you meant to use the word "morally" in your last comment.)

Comment: @Noldorin: I am not a native speaker, so it's quite possible I used the word incorrectly. What I meant is that the statement is correct in a hand-waving and intuitive way, but it would be hard to make the statement rigorous. In other words, it is a [moral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral) of a longer story. Now, is it possible to form an adjective like this? I am not sure and my dictionary tells me that morally doesn't have this meaning. I guess I should go ask [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/) :-)

Comment: Stackexchange sites are great: my usage was [correct](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5076/is-it-possible-to-form-adjective-morally-by-deriving-it-from-the-noun-moral).

Comment: @Marek: Your *grammar* and spelling was correct; only the sentence doesn't make sense. (I'm afraid the answerer of that question was wrong in that respect.) Morality is a philosophical/ethical/sociological question, basically concerning what is "good" and "bad" in humans. Related is the concept of the "moral" of a story. It can't really apply to factual/mathematical statements. In any case, easy mistake to make I'm sure. :)

Comment: @Noldorin, Marek is correct.  I've heard many lecturers and professors use "morally" in that sense; so it's consistent with my observations that "morally" has the definition he's using in the community of practicing physicists.

Comment: Really? I've never heard it used by anyone in Britain, least of all in public. Physicists are known for corrupting language, however! I can concede it's used in some areas though, so fair enough. :) Just a warning: the chance you are understood outside of the physics/science community is about zero.

Comment: And yeah, it seems the dictionaries I've checked don't have this meaning. Perhaps it's becoming a new word within the physics community!

Answer (score 4):

A hint of the special role of angular momentum happens when you look for its conjugate variable. It is angular position, which is *adimensional*. And then you have that any product of a variable times its conjugate has units of action, which are the same units that angular momentum. So classical mechanics already tell us that something is going on.
(Caveat: that you can have the same units with scalar product and with cross product, and the physical meaning is different. If you have checked the pamphlets from German car and enginemakers, you could have noticed the unit "Nm", newton times meter, and the unit "Joule", used differently.)

Answer (score 2):

There exists a very simple and concise semi-classical explanation of the electron's spin angular momentum, without the notion of rotation of any material object: 
Qualitatively speaking, the electron’s spin angular momentum is the electromagnetic field's angular momentum resulting from the combined electromagnetic field surrounding an electron just in such a way that a nonzero Poynting vector circulating around the electron’s dipole axis is created, which also means that a permanent electromagnetic energy flux circulates around the electron’s dipole axis. Relativistic electrodynamics demonstrates that any kind of energy flux is associated with momentum flux (parallel to the Poynting vector) which in itself can be associated with angular momentum relative to a given point or axis of reference. Hence energy circulation around the electron’s dipole axis is equivalent to momentum circulation. If integrated over the whole space around an electron the result is a substantial fraction if not all of an electron’s spin angular momentum being distributed in that space. (See e.g. Feynman Vol. II)

A quantitative assessment of the electromagnetic field angular momentum of an electron  is given in:
 S.M. Blinder: Singularity-free electrodynamics for point charges and dipoles: a classical model for electron self-energy and spin, Eur. J. Phys. 24 (2003)271-275 ([arxiv preprint](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0208072)).

Answer (score 1):

Lubosh wrote: "The angular momentum is defined by the change of the phase of the wave function under rotations, which may come from the dependence of the wave function on space, but also from the transformations of the components of the wave function among each other, which is possible even if everything is localized at a point. So even point-like objects may carry an angular momentum in quantum mechanics, the spin."

In QM it is impossible and is not necessary to impose **R** = 0 (see my blog) to have a system at rest. On the contrary, one has to put **P** = 0. It does not mean point-likeness but **ubiquity** instead.

There is an article by R. Ohanian on [**spin**](http://jayryablon.files.wordpress.com/2008/04/ohanian-what-is-spin.pdf). But I am afraid it is finally a tautology or so.

I think the angular momentum is fundamental. I think that even in Classical Mechanics a description of anything with help of solely three coordinates **R**(t) is too primitive. Generally everything is not point-like and rotates, roughly speaking. So the intrinsic angular momentum **J** is as fundamental as the linear momentum **P** (as well as color, charge, and flavor ;-).

Comment: Apart from negative score, can you give your disagreement points, please? Thanks.

Comment: Vlad, you are in a catch-22 situation. In most cases, you don't want to answer, but only to comment an answer. So, it is not an answer and you get negative scores. But you will not be able to comment until you accummulate 50 points of reputation. Break the loop, look for some questions you can answer in a useful way, and/or do questions of general interest.

Comment: @Vladimir: I'm not sure I agree with your answer, but I'm not sure why you got the down-votes either. (People should indeed leave reasons!)

Comment: @Noldorin: many think of elementary particles in QM as of stable point-like objects whereas there is no stable solution localized at a point all the time. Wide wave packets may be more or less "stable" but they are not point-like objects. The latter case is much more realistic due to necessity of stability while preparing and measuring the spin projections.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not very familiar with QFT, but you saying that all particles (field wave packets) are unstable to some degree? Are there any solitons in QFT?

Comment: @Noldorin: Yes, they (the wave packets) are unstable and the extent of their instability is determined by the preparation device (source, diaphragms, etc.). In addition, if we speak of charge scattering, in the final state you always have many (soft) photons. You cannot scatter without radiation (elastically). It means the initial system is always "broken apart" in some way (inelastic scattering). It is a strict QED result. The system is "large and soft", easy to deformate inelastically. It is incompatible with a soliton-like construction.

Comment: @Vladimir, one of the down-votes was me, sorry for not leaving a comment though. Few reasons: first you say that you can't impose $R=0$ in QM but you can impose $P=0$. Well, this is a complete non-sense because $P$ and $Q$ are treated completely equivalently in QM. When working in $Q$-representation $Q=0$ is a delta-function while $P=0$ is a monochromatic wave. Neither of these is physical. But more importantly, you can change the picture and then in $P$-rep. the interpretation is reverse.

Comment: (cont.) also saying "go see my blog" without even leaving a link to the relevant place as if that solved everything is not the way to go around here ;) It's possible that you have solved all the issues already in the past and have written them up but so much more should you be able to make a concise independent answer. Also, if you need to cite, cite papers people can trust (e.g. arXiv is fine although it's not peer-reviewed).

Comment: (cont.) the part about Ohanian and tautology also doesn't make sense at all. What did he say and what tautology are you referring to? Also, if it's useless, why are you mentioning him in the first place? Just to fill up the space? Also, last paragraph is non-sense, particle approximation often holds very well. Okay, I hope my comments leave you satisfied as to the reasons for the down-vote.

Comment: About Ohanian's and Motl's argument: they both take a multicomponent wave function (a spinor, for example) and show that such a wave function describes a particle with a spin. I think, however, that it is a tautology, not an "explanation". The coordinate dependence of the wave function does not matter, of course (point-like wave packet or not).

Comment: @Marek: $P$ and $Q$ are equivalent in the Hilbert space formalism. I wouldn’t say they are “actually” equiv-t, only because all Lagrangian and Hamiltonian models necessarily include a convex dependence on $P$ while dep-ce on $Q$ may be rather arbitrary. I know there are, mathematically speaking, no eigenstates for continuous spectrum, but… a state tends to have certain position would have increasingly uncertain momentum and, in the limit, unbound total energy. That’s why such quasi-states ($δ(Q-Q_0)$) are unphysical. Contrary, $\exp(ik\cdot Q)$ are rather nice idealization, as Vladimir claims.

Answer (score 1):

As for spin and extended particles, I'd say the contrary: it is not contrary to intuition that point particles have some intrinsic angular momentum, because a point looks as if it had some rotation invariance built-in. The surprising thing is that extended objects have this angular momentum, without a point for the rotational symmetry to pivot in.

Comment: Quantum physics requires a symmetry of the *space-time*, not of an “extended object” as you see it with physical intuition. You will give different answers on the “is this thing rotationally symmetric?” question depending on exact formulation. Can such molecules as water (H₂O) or methane (CH₄) be rotationally symmetric? Geometric intuition says: no, their molecular geometry denies it. But corresponding composite wave functions (of all nuclei and electrons, but with translational symmetry removed) for the ground state are rotationally symmetric.

Answer (score 0):

There is more to it than Spin being intrinsic angular momentum. An electron has an "internal degree of freedom" - to be left handed or right handed, and it can leave point A with RH spin and arrive at B with LH spin. Thus Pauli needs two complex components in his equation. (unlike a photon which arrives with the same spin although it too has LH and RH, so there is no internal degree of freedom ). This is distinct from the spin-vector which defines a direction in space. The two-valuedness comes from rotation being about a bivector which can point up or down along the axis of rotation. One can do spatial rotations either way - and electrons seem to make the distinction - as if there are two kinds, but everything else is the same mass and charge, so we say it is the same particle, with opposite spins. So it seems that there is no necessary connection to either relativity (except for fixing up the Thomas factor in the Pauli eq ) or QFT. Hamilton had the algebra to make the classical distinction between left and right - it is built into quaternion algebra, but he did not see it as a mechanical property of particles - but heck, he did not see the Maxwell equation either.

Comment: With this “two-valuedness comes from rotation being about a bivector which can point up or down along the axis of rotation” you put the cart in front of the horse. How many “components” is needed depends on representations, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29766/why-does-photon-have-only-two-possible-eigenvalues-of-helicity for details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, angular momentum is fundamental, even in classical physics. To understand this, consider the Helmholtz decomposition of momentum density (${\bf p} = \rho {\bf u}$, where $\rho$ is inertial density and $\bf u$ is velocity):
$${\bf p} = {\bf p}_0 + \nabla \Phi + \frac{1}{2} \nabla \times {\bf s}$$
In this equation, ${\bf p}_0$ is a constant which can be set to zero by choice of reference frame, $\Phi$ is a scalar potential associated with irrotational motion, and $\bf s$ is a vector potential associated with incompressible motion.
The vector field ($\bf s$) is the intrinsic (or "spin") angular momentum density. From here on I only consider incompressible motion.

The total angular momentum is:
$$\int{{\bf s} \, d^3 r} = \int{{\bf r} \times {\bf p}\, d^3 r}.$$
This equality can be verified by substituting $(1/2)\nabla \times {\bf s}$ for $\bf p$ and then integrating by parts while assuming no contributions from boundaries (e.g. at infinity). Unlike the "moment of momentum", spin density is independent of the coordinates.
Defining angular velocity by ${\bf w} = (1/2)\nabla \times {\bf u}$, the kinetic energy can be expressed as:
$$\int{\frac{1}{2}{\bf w} \cdot {\bf s} \, d^3 r} = \int{\frac{1}{2}\rho u^2 \, d^3 r}$$
This equality follows from the identity $(\nabla \times {\bf s}) \cdot (\nabla \times {\bf s}) = (\nabla \times \nabla \times {\bf s}) \cdot {\bf s}  + \nabla \cdot ({\bf s} \times (\nabla \times {\bf s}))$, with the assumption that the divergence term integrates to a boundary term that is presumed to be zero.

If the Lagrangian density depends on motion only through the kinetic energy, then the conjugate momentum to angular velocity ($\bf w$) is:
$$\frac{\delta}{\delta {\bf w}} \int{\frac{1}{2}{\bf w} \cdot {\bf s} \, d^3 r} = {\bf s}$$
In this case the factor of $1/2$ disappears because the spin density ($\bf s$) must be regarded as a function of $\bf w$ (integrating by parts twice changes $\int{{\bf w} \cdot {\bf s} \, d^3 r \,}$ to $\int{{\bf s} \cdot {\bf w} \, d^3 r}$). This might seem more obvious if we start with a kinetic energy density of $(1/2)u^2$ and treat $\bf u$ as a function of $\bf w$. Clearly both factors of $u$ contribute to the functional derivative.

Thus, spin density $\bf s$ is the momentum conjugate to angular velocity.

In the above analysis, the "moment of momentum" is not equivalent to orbital angular momentum. It is well known that elastic waves have two types of momentum: the intrinsic momentum of the medium and the wave momentum associated with propagation of energy. It follows that elastic waves also have two types of angular momentum: intrinsic or spin angular momentum associated with rotational motion of the medium, and wave or orbital angular momentum associated with wave propagation. Particle motion is associated with orbital angular momentum because particles propagate through space as waves.
See http://www.classicalmatter.org/ejtpv12i33p43.pdf to see how this relates to the Dirac equation.

Answer (score -2):

Existence of a spin of a particle is of course an indication that the particle is in fact composed of space-separated parts. This does not mean though that the particle is composed of other particles.

For example, at least a part of the electron's spin is currently known to be in fact the orbital momentum of the quantum vacuum fluctuations which are involved by electron's core into rotation. This part is known as anomalous angular momentum of electron.

Another example is photon where the spin can be explained as an order in which the energy contained in electric and magnetic fields rotates around the axis laid along the direction of the photon's propagation.

Comment: -1: this answer is wrong. There is no anomalous angular momentum of the electron. There is an anomlous magnetic moment, but this is not angular momentum, it is current.