# Energy-momentum tensor and gravity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, lagrangian-formalism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Calculating from a given action the energy-momentum tensor $ \tilde{T}_{\mu \nu} $ (differentiating respect to $ \delta g^{\mu \nu}) $ I can create gravity by a generalization of the Einstein field equation?
$$
G_{\mu \nu}=\frac{8 \pi G}{c^4} \tilde{T}_{\mu \nu}\tag{1}
$$
where $\tilde{T}_{\mu \nu}$ is different from the matter energy-momentum tensor.

Comment: What does “create gravity” mean? What is $\alpha$? Why is there a tilde on the $T$? How is this a generalization of the EFE?

Comment: For example, replace matter energy-momentum tensor with the electromagnetic energy momentum tensor

Comment: In GR, the energy-momentum tensor on the right side of the EFE includes *all* non-gravitational forms of energy and momentum. It is not just for matter. Consider, for example, a charged black hole.

Comment: This question is not clear. what do you mean by "generalization of the Einstein field equation"?

Comment: It's more clear now?

Comment: No, EFE is already on the form of eq. (1).

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41662/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/509036/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really you should be thinking about the total action,
$$S = S_{EH}[g] + S_{M}[g,\phi^A] \ ,$$ which includes both the matter action $S_{M}[g,\phi^A]$ and the [Einstein-Hilbert Action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action) $S_{EH}[g]$. Then the variation of the total action with respect to the metric $g_{\mu \nu}$ gives the gravitational field equations, $G_{\mu \nu} = \frac{8 \pi G}{c^4} T_{\mu \nu}$, (see the wiki link for the details). But yes, this leads to the equations you wrote down.

Small note: we *vary* the matter action/Lagrangian with respect to the metric, not differentiate.

Comment: Ok, but  if in general if it's true that makes the variation implies energy-momentum tensor I can use other strange lagrangian not equal to $-mc \int \, ds$ and obtain the interaction with space time?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? A different gravitational Lagrangian or a different matter Lagrangian?

Comment: Adding to $ \int \sqrt{-g} R \, d \Omega $ another lagrangian, you can see it like another matter lagrangian yes

Comment: The *metric* stress-energy tensor is just defined as the variation of the matter Lagrangian with respect to the metric, so you can use whatever you like (so long as it's appropriate). The Einstein tensor necessarily comes from the EH action, so changing that changes the LHS of the field equations.

Comment: Yes, if you define the stress-energy tensor $T_{ab}$ as the variation of this other Lagrangian with respect to $g$, sure!

Comment: Yes,  is used? For example, using electromagnetic energy-momentum tensor? Or a $T_{\mu \nu},$ I don't know, from Dirac lagrangian?

Comment: As long as you're varying the Lagrangian with respect to the metric then you can use any that you like. The examples you listed are fine. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117429/discussion-between-user250057-and-eletie).