# Total energy and momentum in general relativity

Tags: general-relativity, energy, momentum, energy-conservation, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Discussing the energy-momentum tensor in presence of gravitational field, our professor stated that, except some particular cases, it’s not possibile to define a “global” energy and momentum in general relativity. Energy and momentum are only defined locally as densities in the energy-momentum tensor. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the situation is even worse.

1. Globally, energy (momentum) as the integral of an energy (momentum) density over a non-compact space may be divergent/non-integrable, respectively.
2. Locally, there's no well-defined gravitational [stress-energy-momentum (SEM) tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor), cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/227307/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/481613/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41662/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2838/2451) Phys.SE posts and links therein. Nevertheless, check out the notion of a [Landau–Lifshitz pseudotensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy%E2%80%93momentum_pseudotensor), which is not general covariant.

Comment: 1. Just so I don't have nightmares, these topics are out of an introductory course on gr? 2. Our professor just mentioned them, I wanted to know more about it but it's kinda frightening

Comment: 1. Probably not.

Answer (score 2):

A crucial problem is that one cannot unambiguously add vectors applied to different events in spacetime in the non-affine spacetime of GR. Hence you cannot add (integrate) the four momenta (densities)  located on a spatial slice to construct a global quantity. The problem is even more difficult because one also would like that such a sum or integral be also constant in time (some notion of time associated to a family of spatial slices) in some situations, in order to have a meaningful notion.

Scalars can be instead integrated and this is a way out. Instead of trying to define a global four vector one can define a global component of a fourmomentum with respect to a vector field. Mathematically speaking that object is the integral over a spacelike slice of the spacetime of $${T^a}_b\xi^b n_a,$$
where $n$ is the unit normal to the slice and $\xi$ the said vector field. (That slice is a Cauchy surface if assuming that the spacetime is globally hyperbolic.) If this vector is a Killing vector and if $T$ is symmetric, then  the integral of the above quantity is in fact conserved, changing the spatial slice, under mild requirements on the space infinity behaviour of $T$.
If $\xi$ is a Killing  timelike vector field, this procedure gives rise to a meaningful notion of conserved energy in particular.