# Definition of stress-energy tensor for the EFEs and other arbitrary cases

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Suppose that there exists manifold $M$ s.t $T_{\mu\nu} \in M$,  where $T_{\mu\nu} $ is the stress-energy tensor. The einstein field equations are given by $$R_{\mu\nu}-\frac12Rg_{\mu\nu}+\Lambda g_{\mu\nu}=\frac{8\pi G}{c^2}T_{\mu\nu}.$$ One can define the stress-energy tensor for a perfect fluid $T_{\mu\nu}$ as $$T_{\mu\nu}=pg_{\mu\nu}+(p+\rho)U_{\mu}U_{\nu} ,$$ where $U$ is the four-velocity. The stress-energy tensor has also been derived as the E-H action using functional derivatives (confusing). I have seen similar questions on the site, however they do not answer this question. What definition would an individual use to set up the stress-energy tensor specifically for the Einstein Field Equations? Is there a definition true for any type of fluid and or any type of situation one could encounter in GR? Is the Einstein-Hilbert action the correct definiton?

Answer (score 1):

1. Briefly speaking, the [stress-energy-momentum (SEM) tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) that constitutes the matter side of the  [EFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations) is the [symmetric/Hilbert SEM tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Hilbert_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) for the matter (=non-gravitational) fields of the physical system.
2. The functional derivative of the [Einstein-Hilbert (EH) action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Hilbert_action) yields the [Einstein tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_tensor), i.e. the gravitational/geometric side of the EFE.
3. Interestingly, there's no well-defined gravitational SEM tensor, cf. e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/227307/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/481613/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41662/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2838/2451), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/612393/2451) Phys.SE posts and links therein.

Comment: In the definition, using the Einstein-Hilbert action, is defined using the functional derivative. The definiton follows as $$T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta S_{matter}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}=T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{-2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\partial(\sqrt{-g}L_{matter})}{\partial g^{\mu\nu}}=-2\frac{\partial (L_{matter})}{\partial g^{\mu\nu}}+g_{\mu\nu}L_{matter}$$, is $$2\frac{\partial (L_{matter})}{\partial g^{\mu\nu}}+g_{\mu\nu}L_{matter}$$ now the partial derivative or still the functional derivative with a switch in notation?

Comment: The formulas using partial derivatives are not correct if $L$ depends on derivatives of the metric field.

Comment: Thats makes sense. Now, for the functional derivative with respect to the metric $$\frac{\delta L_{matter}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}$$, which definition of the functional derivative would It follow? Would It follow the same-spacetime definition and just give me the EL equations?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: 1. How would one determine the matter part of the Lagrangian? 2. Would It be the normal formula i.e. $$L=\frac12g_{\mu\nu}\dot x^{\mu}\dot x^{\nu}?$$

Comment: 1.That would depend on what matter one is trying to model.