# Relativistic Doppler effect and Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, visible-light, doppler-effect

Consider the situation below. I’m at a point in space along with a bunch of detector away from any gravitational field. I see a star moving away from me at a relative speed of $$v$$by measuring the velocity I can know the frequency shift of the light. That is the redshift. 
$$f=F*\sqrt{\frac{1-(v/c)}{1+(v/c)}}$$

Here f is the observed frequency and F is the source frequency.

Now consider this. For a photon of light which is near to the source, the energy can be given by $$E=h*F$$
But the same photon near me or my detector( which is close to me) will have the energy $$E’=h*f$$
Since $$F>f$$
Therefore $$E>E’$$
*from the above Doppler shift equation

Since this energy is lost where exactly is it lost ?

Does it get absorbed by the ‘fabric of space time’?

But if energy is conserved and $$E=E’$$
Then what am I missing from the above equations?

Comment: Energy is not invariant under Lorentz transformations. I.e. different observer disagree. For each observer energy is conserved though (if you forget about an expanding universe)

Comment: @lalala: That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Energy is not invariant under Lorentz transformations. I.e. different observer disagree. For each observer energy is conserved though (if you forget about an expanding universe). For GR see: [Is the law of conservation of energy still valid?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35431/is-the-law-of-conservation-of-energy-still-valid)

Comment: Thanks for the answer . But what if the universe is expanding? Does that mean that$$E=E’$$ or does it mean that energy is lost?