# Why energy cannot be created nor destroyed if the Universe is still growing in size?

Tags: energy, cosmology, energy-conservation, space-expansion, universe

Why energy cannot be created nor destroyed if the Universe is still growing in size?There is creation of new space and infact this space is so energetic that causes 'Hubble flow' of matter...

Comment: *this space is so energetic* What does that mean?

Comment: The Hubble flow is an illusion, something stationary looks like moving because there is new extra space in between.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the law of conservation of energy still valid?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35431/)

Comment: Dark Matter + Normal Matter -------->  Space + Energy