# Will energy ever run out?

Tags: energy, gravity, energy-conservation, stars

Gravity is the source of all energy and it will never go away. So that means there will always be energy for us right? I have seen some places say that energy will go away eventually and the last star dies. But it doesn't make sense because won't gravity just make a new star?

If you don't believe that gravity is the source of all energy, hear me out. Gravity was what pulled the Sun together along with the solar system and is what keeps them together. The Sun provides heat and light which created life. Life consumes life for more energy to do things like making more energy or making things that create more energy such as solar panels, oil drills, wind turbines, etc.

Comment: In mainstream physics, gravity is *not* the source of all energy. There are seventeen fundamental quantum fields in the Standard Model, none of them having anything to do with gravity, and *every one* of them can have energy, even if gravity didn’t exist.

Comment: It's difficult to know whether you're wondering about the eventual fate of the universe or the eventual fate of life on earth. Either way, gravity is not the source of all energy, and even if it were, the fact that gravity exists does not imply what we can get useful energy out of it. It seems that you're very naive about science and physics, which is fine, but it's difficult to accurately answer a question composed entirely of statements of things that aren't valid. Even your literal questions are just statements but with a "?" tacked on. Please try to formulate a single real question.

Comment: Philosophically, Does it matter? This is essentially the same question as whether the universe is cyclic or not. If so, many iterations of the universe have already happened, and many more are to come. If not, the universe cools to the point of no molecular interaction and possibly not even any subatomic interactions. The important part of the question is, how can possessing this knowledge improve the state of things here at the mid-point where we find ourselves?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, energy will always be available - after all, we know that energy is conserved in a closed system. The amount of energy is not the important factor here. The important factor is the amount of energy that can be extracted from a system to do work. This is called “free energy” in thermodynamics, and it is a finite resource.

Even if the universe has an infinite lifetime, it will eventually reach a state where everything is at the same temperature and all matter in the universe is inside black holes. There will still be plenty of energy in the universe, but none of it will be available to do work.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some perspectives which might be helpful for you. I'll omit the math and most of the other hard stuff.

Gravity *in and of itself* is not a source of "free lunch" eternal energy from which we can charge batteries, heat our homes, or produce useful work. The only sense in which gravity powers our world is that gravity is what makes stars out of gas and dust, and the radiant energy given off by stars as they fuse hydrogen is in turn what powers our world.

Stars need gas, dust, and gravity to form, and when all the available gas and dust has been pulled together into stars, new stars will stop being formed and after the existing stars use up their stores of fuel, they'll either blow up or fade out- and the last of their radiant energy will dissipate away, and the universe will cool down to dark nothingness.

Answer (score -2):

I think that energy can't ever run out, is Answer is in one simple principle laws of conservation of energy. You can check it out on net. As far as what I believe the ultimate source of energy for the whole universe was big bang , our universe is still using the energy release in that explosion and really the amount of energy now and then is equal that is because, energy can neither be created nor be destroyed. The things is our universe is expanding and hence energy is getting distributed equally (I think so) so our universe is getting colder also and that results in less energy concentration at a place for complex functions such as life and revolution. Some thing destroys and some new thing is created to conserve energy. And that is how universe works.

Comment: This is incorrect: see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35431

Comment: Thanks you , would remember it