# Explanation for the notion that physical laws break down at the Big Bang

Tags: quantum-gravity, big-bang, theory-of-everything

I've often heard the phrase "physical laws break down at the big bang".

Why is this?  Divide by zero?

Please provide the mathematics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations) to the  equations whose solutions lead to the model of the expanding universe from an initial discontinuity called Big Bang.

> The Friedmann equations are a set of equations in physical cosmology that govern the expansion of space in homogeneous and isotropic models of the universe within the context of general relativity.

The article gives the equations derived from General Relativity, whose [solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations#Useful_solutions) provide the functions for modeling the BB cosmological model.

A simplified form can be found [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/astro/fried.html).

[Here is another link](http://universeinproblems.com/index.php/Solutions_of_Friedman_equations_in_the_Big_Bang_model#Problem_7:_age_of_the_Universe) for solutions of the equations leading to a big bang model. For example time is in the denominator in [this solution](http://universeinproblems.com/index.php/Solutions_of_Friedman_equations_in_the_Big_Bang_model#Problem_1:_matter_or_radiation_in_a_flat_Universe) for the density $\rho$, giving infinity at time $t=0$.
$$\rho(t)=\frac{1}{32\pi G t^2}$$

One sees that as t=0 is approached the matter density blows up. General Relativity tells us that in the region of high masses the physical laws we have studied and modeled in flat space change and may not hold in the form we know them ([for example conservation of energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2597/energy-conservation-in-general-relativity)). The flat space approximation does not hold. Approaching  zero time where the density tends to infinity is even worse, indeterminacy in masses means also indeterminacy in the laws governing space time.

Comment: is the breakdown at `0` for `rho` the divide by zero indeterminate form?

Comment: yes, the value  tends to infinity

Comment: is the breakdown that `rho(0)` tends to infinity or is indeterminate?  would you mind explaining why which is the problem?

Comment: Physical laws are not made to deal with infinities. I know that there exists many mathematical infinities but I have not seen them to be useful in mathematical physical models. Physical laws are already modified in the region of large masses. As density tends to infinity the distortions of spacetime can no longer be approximated by flat space, where our physical laws are determined so the physical laws become indeterminate too.

Comment: would you mind expanding that explanation in your answer?  extremely interesting

Comment: There's also the issue that physics at the Planck scale is not fully understood