# Is the total mass of the universe constant in time?

Tags: energy, mass, universe, popular-science, mass-energy

Is the total mass of the universe constant in time?

Comment: What doubt do you have?

Comment: I don't know why this person gets 2 down votes. Actually his question is nice.His wordings may not be right as he may be poor in English.

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR I downvoted because of the "This questions does not show any research effort" reason. Good questions put forth some effort to answer themselves and explain where the OP doesn't understand something. This makes no such effort.

Answer (score 2):

Since mass and energy are the same according to Einstein's equation I would say that mass is not constant for the universe because the law of conservation of energy has been proven false. It is so because the space itself in which the processes take place is expanding.

You can get a detailed article about it here-http://www.preposterousuniverse.com/blog/2010/02/22/energy-is-not-conserved/

Answer (score 2):

Mass is obviously not conserved, as $E=mc^2$ state. But if you want to consider the total mass of the  Universe, the problem is that "total" mass (energy) in General Relativity is not well defined, see: [Energy conservation in General Relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2597/energy-conservation-in-general-relativity)