# If energy can't be created and can't destroyed

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, big-bang

Then wouldn't be logical that all the energy in the big-bang-created-universe will equal to the energy that was released by the Big Bang?  The sum is zero?

**Edit**
The cited dup is asking "Did the law of conservation of energy apply to the earliest moments of the Big Bang? If so, what theoretical physics supports this?"

I want to know whether the source of all energy is the big bang or not.  thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10309/50583

Comment: Unlike in mathematics, logic doesn't work in physics, you need to have measurements that back it up.

Comment: @CuriousOne Logic works everywhere. Sometimes the answers are not liked :-) But, yes, Physics is stamp collecting too, just like the rest.

Comment: @Zuslx - The amount of energy present at T 0.00000.... is whatever it was. How much energy was used and conservation thereof are different issues.

Answer (score 1):

Energy, in the context of the universe and the models used in describing it , is in the [stress energy tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor), which contains the energy/mass transformations.

The accepted at the moment model for the universe is the [Big Bang model,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bang) as summarized in this plot , is a good fit to the available observations using all known physics to date.

[image: bigbang]

Known physics is encapsulated in the [standard model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics. Energy conservation is a strict law within this. In contrast, General Relativity has [a grey region  on energy conservation.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2597/energy-conservation-in-general-relativity). [See also this discussion.](http://motls.blogspot.gr/2010/08/why-and-how-energy-is-not-conserved-in.html)  As all the data we have from the beginning of the universe are contained in the [cosmic microwave background radiation, CMB,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background)  in the accepted *model* for the universe, one can be sure of the modeling from 10^-32 seconds to  380.000 years when the photons decoupled from the soup. There standard model particle physics is used where energy conservation is strict.

The time from the beginning of the universe to the 10^-32 seconds , the end of the inflation period  in this plot, the model is completely mathematical as no inflatons have been observed experimentally. Its acceptance is due to its success in describing the homogeneity observed in the CMB.

In any case there is the question "where did the energy come from, to create the Big Bang". This is still a research question with various models proposed.

From 10^-32 seconds and  on to the right of the plot, the standard model physics is assumed as holding and there of course energy conservation holds strictly.

The summary is that after 10^-32 seconds the energy residing in the universe is conserved.