# What is the mathematical meaning and condition for the Noether's charge to be conserved locally?

Tags: conservation-laws, symmetry, field-theory, noethers-theorem, gauge-invariance

Noether's theorem for continuous symmetries gives rise to a conserved charge. *Mathematiccally*, what does it mean for a charge to be (i) locally and (ii) globally conserved? I think, a locally conserved charge *needs not* arise only from a local gauge symmetry. For example, conservation of energy is a local conservation law which arises from translational invariance in time.

Comment: Are you suggesting that time translation invariance is a global symmetry? It's not. That's why energy isn't globally conserved

Comment: @Jim- Poincare symmetries are not gauge symmetries. If the parameters used to represent the transformations of a group are independent of spacetime, then that transformation is global. Right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quantity $Q$ with a density $\rho(t,x)$ (such that $Q(V) = \int_V \rho(t,x)\mathrm{d}x$ is the amount of $Q$ inside $V$) is *globally conserved* if the global amount of $Q$ is constant, i.e. $\int\rho(x)$ does not depend on time if we integrate over the entire space $M$: 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\int_M \rho(t,x)\mathrm{d}x=0\tag{1}$$
Such a quantity is *locally* conserved if for every volume $V$ we have that $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\rho = \nabla j,\tag{2}$$
where $j$ is the current density of $Q$, i.e. the function says *how much of $Q$ crosses a given unit area in a given unit time*.

Noether's theorem says that to every quasi-symmetry of the action there exists a locally conserved quantity. The notion of "local conservation" is unrelated to the notion of "local symmetries" (i.e. gauge symmetries).

There is a slightly different notion of local vs. global conservation in the context of e.g. general relativity (The following is paraphrased from [this article by Baez](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/GR/energy_gr.html), for more discussion on global conservation of energy in GR, see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2597/50583) and its linked questions): Here, you'll often find people stating that something (like energy or momentum) is locally but not globally conserved, and what it means is that while the differential statement like $\dot{\rho} = \nabla j$ holds, its classically equivalent integral formulation 
$$\int_V \rho(t_1,x)\mathrm{d}x - \int_V \rho(t_2,x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{\partial V}\int_{t_0}^{t_1} \rho(t,x)\mathrm{d}t\mathrm{d}S\tag{3}$$
doesn't hold if $\rho,Q$ are not scalars, but instead vectors/tensors as in the case of the energy-momentum tensor. In this case, the differential equation is  a "local" statement, and the integral formulation is a "global" statement.