# How does Hawking Radiation not violate energy conservation?

Tags: black-holes, energy-conservation, quantum-information, hawking-radiation

If Hawking Radiation is produced by particle-antiparticle pairs forming from the vacuum, with one particle being absorbed by the black hole and one escaping, how is the original energy required to create the pair not adding to the overall energy of the universe if the two do not annihilate?

Comment: possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/30597/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2597/84967 and links therein.