# How does an expanding universe and a constant-density vacuum energy not violate energy conservation?

Tags: cosmology, energy-conservation, space-expansion, universe, vacuum

As per the title. I'm probably thinking too naively in a classical way, but intuitively it seems to me that:

1. the presence of vacuum energy at fixed density throughout all space and,
2. an expanding universe

would imply that more and more energy is constantly added to the universe.

I am assuming we have not given up on energy conservation quite yet, so where is the catch?

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/10402/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/405608/123208 and the links therein. TL;DR: GR doesn't  have global conservation of energy, or that it's even possible to define a global energy for the whole universe. But local conservation of energy is still ok.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is dark energy consistent with conservation of mass and energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33404/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Energy conservation is equivalent to the Lagrangian's partial time derivative being $0$. In an FLRW spacetime, this fails. (In fact, total energy isn't always even well-defined in general relativity.)

While ordinary matter has a density proportional to $a^{-3}$ in a universe of scale factor $a$, dark energy is far from the only component of the universe that doesn't work like that, resulting in a volume-dependent contribution to total mass-energy. Radiation has an $a^{-4}$ density, so actually diminishes over time. This is why a radiation-dominated era preceded the matter-dominated era.