# Energy can't be created or destoryed?

Tags: energy, cosmology, energy-conservation, universe, big-bang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conservation law of energy and Big Bang?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/conservation-law-of-energy-and-big-bang)

If energy can't be created or destroyed then how did the big bang create energy? and if energy can't be created then does that mean that there's a set amount of energy in our universe?

Comment: Scientist tends to the [zero-energy universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-energy_universe) which have no problem poping out of nowhere and nothing.

Comment: I'd say that Big bang created everything including "Time" of your clock...

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35431/2451 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10309/2451

Comment: Good question. There is still a lot we don't understand about the early universe and your question essentially reduces to how did the universe with its energy content pop into existence. Whether it popped into existence in the first place is still a matter of debate (since one can say Einsteinian time started with the universe and therefore one cannot talk about _before_ the universe). Until we figure it out, not knowing is the exciting part about physics as lots of people try to figure this out.