# Energy neither created nor destroyed. Then where energy comes from?

Tags: energy, cosmology, energy-conservation, universe, big-bang

We are stating that energy neither be created nor be destroyed. Then where does it come from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conservation law of energy and Big Bang?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10309/)

Answer (score 0):

As you said it cannot be created, so why would you think that it should come from somewhere? It just is. In physics this is called an initial condition.

Answer (score 0):

According to principle of conservation of energy, one form of energy can be converted in other form (like heat into light etc.) but it cannot be formed / generated on its own. Thus it is plausible that energy must have been created for the first time when Universe was created. According to big bang theory Universe was created with collision of particles of matter with anti-particles throwing apart parts of universe with tremendous speed thereby creating different forms of huge energy like heat, light, sound motion for the first time.