# Photons in expanding space: how is energy conserved?

Tags: cosmology, photons, energy-conservation, space-expansion, cosmological-inflation

If a photon (wave package) redshifts (stretches) travelling in our expanding universe, is its energy reduced?

If so, where does that energy go?

Comment: The same question has been asked several times, in different guises, on this website. Please see: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1327/829 http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2597/829 http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10309/829 http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296/829 The answer basically is: you need to be careful what you mean by "energy conservation" in the context of general relativity.

Comment: The questions are mostly about energy conservation on cosmological scale, I was wandering about the local phenomenon - though it seems to be the matter of quantum-mechanic and gravitational unification :/

Comment: This should be closed. It's an exact duplicate of the questions Willie Wong has linked to.

Comment: Since Marek's post in 1327 covers at least 95% of this question, second the move to close. Short addendum: there is no local coordinate-independent measure of gravitational energy, nor can there be one, because its existence would violate the equivalence principle. So the answer is just "it isn't!"

Comment: Marek said: "One can consider various notions of energy in General Relativity but these concepts are pretty messy and one is pretty much forced to talk only about energy locally in some small volume." - exactly what I am asking

Comment: Ted's answer below seems to address the matter of local definitions more squarely that the answers I read on 1327, and I am tempted to leave this open just for that reason. However, it is more the statement of the answer rather than the content which is different so I could still be talked into using my diamond power close. Thought?

Comment: In some other stackexchanges, I believe the moderators will close a duplicate question and move a good answer for this question to be an answer to the original question. This gathers all the good answers together, and avoids the confusion of duplicate questions. Is that possible here?

Comment: @Willie Wong In what way is this a duplicate of the one you are referring to? As far as I can see it is a completely different question. A recent question of mine  happens to be a duplicate of this.

Comment: @AlanGee: (a) I didn't vote to close, I only noted questions with **very** similar nature. (b) For why they are similar/dissimilar, I think the 6 comments between yours and my original one does a fair job discussing the issue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you say you're talking about what happens locally (in a small volume), I'll answer from that point of view. The usual formulation of energy conservation in such a volume is that energy is conserved *in an inertial reference frame*. In general relativity, there are no truly inertial frames, but in a sufficiently small volume, there are reference frames that are approximately inertial to any desired level of precision. If you restrict your attention to such a frame, *there is no cosmological redshift*. The photon's energy when it enters one side of the frame is the same as the energy when it exits the other side. So there's no problem with energy conservation.

The (apparent) failure of energy conservation arises only when you consider volumes that are too large to be encompassed by a single inertial reference frame.

To be slightly more precise, in some small volume $V=L^3$ of a generic expanding Universe, imagine constructing the best possible approximation to an inertial reference frame. In that frame, observers near one edge will be moving with respect to observers near the other edge, at a speed given by Hubble's Law (to leading order in $L$). That is, in such a frame, the observed redshift is an ordinary Doppler shift, which causes no problems with energy conservation.

If you want more detail, David Hogg and I wrote about this at considerable (perhaps even excessive!) length in [an AJP paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0808.1081).

Comment: I see, so photon did not actually lost any energy, but it is measured in a different reference frame.

Comment: @troyaner: Saying that the photon "did not actually lost any energy" is not really right. It assumes there is some way to talk about conservation of energy nonlocally, and there just isn't.

Comment: If measured in comoving coordinates the photon actually lost its energy.

Comment: That's true. The quantity energy-as-measured-in-comoving-coordinates is not a conserved quantity. Personally, I'd rather not interpret that sentence as meaning that energy is not conserved, but rather as meaning that energy-as-measured-in-comoving-coordinates is not a concept that rightfully deserves to be considered as "energy."

Comment: Why do people have to make this all so complicated. Why not just accept the fact that photons in the past were less energetic than their modern day counterparts. I.e that dark energy is converted to normal energy during  expansion.

Comment: @AlanGee I think because the complication/nuance is viewed as being "worth it," considering that we currently (I think) have no positive evidence of the claim *dark energy is converted to normal energy during expansion.*

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin  What people are overlooking with the expansion of the universe is the contraction of time that must accompany the dilation of length. There is a work neutral exchange of momentum to energy over time in much the same way as there is an exchange of energy to momentum over space due to gravity. We see an increasing wavelength (because its easy) but we don't see the decreasing period of waves (because its hard) just as we don't see the decreasing length of waves in Grav'l Len Con, but we can deduce that it happens. I know this contradicts what I said before, but I know more now.

Comment: Can you provide sources? And people probably don't want to accept something unless there's justifications for it.... and I don't know energy and momentum are converted to each other either....

Answer (score -4):

It goes to make work to expand the universe against the forces of gravity and inertia. This is like adiabatically expanding volume of gas: the gas becomes cooler as the volume increases. Where the energy goes?

Comment: wow, so you are suggesting that (0°K) shielding of some volume and reducing the photons inside can affect the expansion of space-time in this volume? I'm not sure.

Comment: I cannot understand your concern. How would you reduce the photons inside? If by contacting with a body, the energy will go to heat.

Comment: I cannot prove the opposite, but expansion of space fueled by redshifting of photons seems improbable and has at least two issues - cause-and-effect and universality of physical laws. (is the expansion of space accelerated in photon-rich environment e.g. stars? I take a 0°K black-body, does the space ceases to expand inside it?)

Comment: If you place a photon such that it moves back and forward in alternating directions (say between two fixed mirrors), it will not loose any energy unless the distance between the mirrors is expanding. The same happens inside a star or any other medium where photons chaotically move in random directions.

Comment: To make photon loose energy due to expansion of universe you have either make it move only in one direction or make it move between two mirrors fixed at their local place but such that the distance between them grows due to expansion of universe. If the mirrors are locally at rest, but placed far enough to experience increase in distance between them due to universal expansion, all the energy the photon looses due to expanding volume between the mirrors goes to the expansion of the universe.

Comment: Regarding cause and effect, take a syringe and quickly expand its internal volume. The gas inside will cool. Its energy went to expansion of the syringe but was not its cause.

Comment: Also note that not only protons but any moving object in an expanding universe looses its kinetic energy. That is interstellar gas also becomes cooler and its density and pressure decreases.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. There is no known conserved, scalar measure of mass-energy that applies to cosmological spacetimes.

Comment: Second @Ben Crowell.

Comment: @ Ben Crowell one can speak about a closed volume, enclosed by comoving walls. There is no need to speak about universe as a whole.

Comment: This answer is correct. Even if you think there is something wrong with energy conservation the effect that radiation has on the expansion rate of the universe if determined by the Friedmann equations which are not controversial  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations .Of course the effect is too small to be detectable which is perhaps why some people are confused. In any case energy conservation works perfectly well in this case see http://vixra.org/abs/1305.0034

Comment: No, this is not an apt analogy. A universe with only cold dark matter could expand in a similar fashion as one with cold dark matter and radiation. Under this analogy, one could ask where the work comes from if there is only CDM. Radiation might lose energy to expansion, but that does not mean that energy must go into fuelling the expansion

Answer (score -4):

This answer was intended to stay in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/118590/with-redshift-energy-is-lost-where-does-it-go).

Conservation of the energy is (it used to be) a cornerstone in the physics framework. Without that *anything* can happen.

Let's see how energy can be conserved.

**Galaxies are moving** dragged by the space expansion. When atoms are in motion the doppler effect will shift the spectra of the emitted photons, as @anna answer showed in the link above.

The proton-to-electron mass ratio, $\frac{m_e}{m_p}$ has been measured constant along the history of the universe, but nothing can be said about the constancy of the electron's mass (to the downvoters: a reference is welcome).

The photon's energy obey the Sommerfeld relation, $E_{jn}=-m_e*f(j,n,\alpha,c)$, as [seen here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Energy_levels), and it **is evident that a redshifted spectrum is obtained with a larger $m_e$.**

The spectra lines are not only due to the Hydrogen atom; there are other spectral lines due to molecular interactions, due to electric/magnetic dipoles, etc, and so the electromagnetic interaction,the Coulomb's law, $F_{}=\frac{1}{4\cdot \pi\cdot \varepsilon_0}\cdot \frac{q1\cdot q2}{d^2}$ must be analyzed.

If we scale the mass $m_e$ by the relation $\alpha(t)$ (not related with the above fine structure constant), where $t$ is time (past), we should also scale the charge and the distance by the same factor, giving *exactly* the same value $F_{}=\frac{1}{4\cdot \pi\cdot \varepsilon_0}\cdot \frac{q_1\cdot q_2\cdot \alpha^ 2(t)}{d^2\cdot \alpha^2(t)}$. Thus the system with and without the transformation behaves in the same manner. The same procedure shows that the universal gravitational law is also insensitive to the scaling of the atom. This should not be a complete surprise because the scaling of masses, charges, time units and distances is routinely used on computer simulations that mimic the universe in a consistent way.

**The conclusion is that there is no way to distinguish between the spectrum of an atom in motion and the one of a scaled atom.**

The photons that were emitted by a larger atom in the past are received now without any change in its wavelength and, thus, **with energy conservation**.

The mainstream viewpoint not being aware that scaling the atom gave the same observational results, adopted the receding interpretation long time ago. As a consequence the models derived from that interpretation (BB, Inflation, DE, DM, ) do not obey the general laws of the universe, namely the energy conservation principle.

My viewpoint offers **a cause for the space expansion**.  You can think about that, unless you are comfortable with: 'space expands', period, without a known cause.

Physics is about causes and whys, backed by proper references. 
I used the most basic laws to show that another viewpoint is inscribed in the laws of nature. I've only used **Basic laws** that do not need to be peer-reviewed as they are **mainstream physics**.

When I graduated as electronic engineer, long time ago, I accepted naively that the fields (electrostatic and gravitational) are sourced by the particles, and expand at $c$ speed, without being drained. But now, older but not senile, I assume without exception, that in the universe there are no 'free lunches' and thus the energy must be transferred from the particles (shrinking) to the fields (growing).

This new viewpoint is formalized and compared to the $\Lambda CDM$ model in a rigourous document, with the derivation of the scale relation $\alpha(t)$ that corresponds to the universe's evolution, at:
[A self-similar model of the Universe unveils the nature of dark energy](http://vixra.org/pdf/1107.0016v1.pdf)
preceded by older documents at arxiv:
[Cosmological Principle and Relativity - Part I](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0205033)
[A relativistic time variation of matter/space fits both local and cosmic data](http://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/0208365v1)

**Ps: Can someone provide a way to distinguish between the spectrum of an atom in motion and the one of a scaled atom ?** (maybe probing the atom's nucleus and find the isotope ratio's abundance (D/H evolution and others) as Mr Webb has done)

Comment: I have a problem with this sentence: " As a consequence the models derived from that interpretation (BB, Inflation, DE, DM, ) do not obey the general laws of the universe, namely the energy conservation principle." The models do obey the laws of the universe. However, in GR it is generally understood that there is no "conservation of energy" law. There is only conservation of the energy-momentum tensor. In a non-expanding universe, this leads to energy conserved as well. But energy-momentum is still conserved in expanding universes; energy itself is not, but that is not an issue

Comment: the problem is "a way to distinguish between the spectrum of an atom in motion and the one of a scaled atom". If you like I'can remove that sentence, because I do not wish to make comparisons with SM (broad questions are outside of the spirit of the site).

Comment: " is evident that a redshifted spectrum is obtained with a larger $m_e$. "

How would you distinguish this change in the spectrum from e.g. lowering of $c$, which is also present in the formula?
in general you need robust justification for **assuming change of natural constants**, not other way round.

Comment: The limits on by how much $\alpha$ can change with time are now very small and come from observations of absorption along the lines of sight to distant quasars. These techniques do indeed distinguish between a doppler shift and a "scaled atom" because fine structure splitting depends on $\alpha^4$, whilst overall energies of transitions depend on $\alpha^2$.

Comment: @RobJeffries The constants are indeed constants. I scale the atom and keep constants the same, because the books on physics are word by word, value by value the same for a scaled atom.  Someone asserted elsewere with conviction: No change in the atoms were detected. Sure it is so.