# Work and energy: law of conservation of energy?

Tags: energy, energy-conservation, universe

According to the law of conservation of energy:

> **Energy can neither be created nor be destroyed**

Then how did energy come into existence?

Comment: Because we don't know. This field of science is still growing. We belive the universe gets its energy and mass from a explosion called big bang.

Comment: that is what i was asking that how universe was having energy before big bang

Comment: There was nothing before the big bang.

Comment: There are cases where energy conservation may not be true due to the breaking of space-time symmetry like due to universe expansion.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2838/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19216/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @YoungKindaichi can you please briefly explain There are cases where energy conservation may not be true due to the breaking of space-time symmetry like due to universe expansion

Comment: https://medium.com/starts-with-a-bang/is-energy-conserved-when-photons-redshift-in-our-expanding-universe-5352bca86652#:~:text=Exactly%20as%20much%20as%20they%20lost%20when%20the%20Universe%20expanded.&text=So%20yes%2C%20it's%20actually%20true,in%20the%20form%20of%20work.

Answer (score 1):

Energy is not something really *existing* in nature (i.e. outside of our minds),but an integral of motion - a fruit of human imagination. It reflects the fact the equations governing the universe are such, that they have integrals of motion, which can be tied to the fundamental symmetries. Equations are of course also a human invention, rather than a property of nature.

People in high-energy physics and cosmology will perhaps disagree with me, and for good reasons. Yet, I think this understanding of energy can take you rather far.