# Law of Conservation of Energy and Matter

Tags: energy-conservation

In one of the articles in Arabic I read that the law of conservation of energy and matter is wrong. Is this true? I was confused when hearing this. What I know is that there is a law in physics that says that energy and matter do not perish and do not come from nothing. Is this true or is this law not valid anymore?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19216/2451 and links therein.

Comment: If by matter you mean mass, mass is conserved only in classical mechanics and electrodynamics. For high velocities and energies one has to use Lorenz transformations to define the kinematics    http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/ltrans.html  . Mass  is not an additive conserved quantity but depends or the length of the four vectors. Only energy momentum and angular momentum are conserved quantities in this frame..