What is energy, and why and when is it conserved?
In which field of physics can I find a solution to this question:
What is energy, and why and when is it conserved?
When I asked a similar question to my professors and peers, they said, 'We discovered the conservation law through experimentation.' (In the first place, they don't even provide a proper definition of energy.)
My thoughts are like, 'Really? How did scientists conduct experiments to confirm that this strange formula (1/2 * m * v^2 for kinetic energy and the concept of potential energy, assuming that all mechanical energy is either kinetic or potential) actually conserves? How did they even come up with this formula and assert that it’s conserved?'
I have a similar doubt about momentum and angular momentum.

You should have been shown some of these experiments in high school science class. If you haven't seen them for whatever reason, then you can find videos on a well known video streaming site that starts with You and ends with Tube. You could also replicate them fairly easily at home. If you need precision data, then you will have to redo the work of likes like Copernicus and Kepler and observe planetary motion for years. That's a lot of work, though. I would prefer standing on the shoulders of giants over showing that much enthusiasm for physics, to be honest...

Émilie du Châtelet wrote extensively on the philosophical basis of energy, and other foundational physics topics.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3014/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/19216/2451 and links therein.

The Physics book I used (decades ago in years 11 and 12) began with the idea of Impulse as Force x time interval, and showed that it is the same as the change in momentum. Newton's 3rd Law then leads to conservation of momentum. Work was defined analogously as Force x distance traveled, and when you look at what work is the change in, you get the kinetic energy formula. These quantities turned out to be useful, partly because in many situations they are conserved. Past that it is experiments and generalisations.

@FlatterMann iam ig i want to edit the question anyways my exact question is wht is energy and why does it conserve,and nvm the remaining part of the question( how in the world scientists   define the weird quantity  and identified that defined quantity conserves (without any proof) and initiated to do experiments ...)

@peter thts not my question and ur 11 and 12 books dont tell abut why does energy conserves ,it intially assumes tht energy conserves and proceeds to solve problems but my question is why does energy conserves?/

@PM2Ring iam not interested in philosphy wht iam looking for is wht is defintion of energy and why does it conserves..

Energy is the ability of a system to perform work on another system. That's high school. Energy is conserved in systems that are symmetric under time translation. That's Noether's theorem and it's first year university level physics.

define work?? @FlatterMann

Work is usually defined as force times displacement. We are introducing it in high school before we introduce energy. We motivate that work is conserved with the simple machines chapter in typical physics textbooks.

@FlatterMann, can you explain how work is conserved? I've never heard this statement before (I guess it’s analogous to saying impulse is conserved). Also, can you try to formulate energy using your definition of energy?"

I told you all there is to it. Energy has a 13 word definition and work a five word definition. If you went to high school you have heard all of this before. It's OK if you can't remember. The world has a couple million physicists who can. That's all we need.

What is energy? See the above comments. How do we know it is conserved? Because assuming energy is conserved lets us describe correctly how the world works. If energy were not conserved our descriptions would be wrong. In the 20th century nuclear energy was discovered, and we discovered the existing theory was inadequate. As a result our understanding of energy was changed, and now the theory of energy conservation is consistent with a bigger body of knowledge about how the world works.
