# If energy is neither created nor destroyed, where is the extra space coming from?

Tags: cosmology, energy-conservation, space-expansion, universe, cosmological-inflation

I've been learning about many aspects of science all of my life, and have come to understand the following:

1. Energy is neither created, nor destroyed. (Classical Physics)
2. Space is expanding. (Cosmology)
3. In a vacuum, there are virtual particles being created and destroyed, where a pair of virtual particles have an average lifespan of $n$ seconds. (Quantum Mechanics)
4. The average energy in a volume of vacuum is 0 over a duration of $m$ seconds. (Quantum Mechanics)

My question is, since the volume is increasing resulting in a larger instantaneous vacuum energy, even though the vacuum energy is 0 on average, does this mean that there is new energy being created in the universe ?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1327/2451 and links therein.

Comment: It is called "dark energy" because a lot of energy is entering the universe". Note the answers in the duplicate, conservation of energy is strict in local systems, as you note GR is iffy. Please note that  loop virtual particles by mathematical construction do not conserve energy and momentum, as they are continuously  variable  ( their fourvector is off mass shell) within an integral , and particularly in vacuum cannot exist if there are no real input four vector particles .