# Spin of a particle (Quantum Mechanics)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

1. Why the intrinsic spin cannot be expressed in terms of polar vectors or the orbital variables $\bf r$ and $\bf p$?
2. Or, why do we need matrix representation for Spin?

Comment: ...what? I have no idea what you mean - spin has *nothing to do at all* with position $r$ or momentum $p$.

Comment: I thought what if Spin is analogous to angular momentum which I know is not true.

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/822/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

Spin is an intrinsic quantity of a particle similar to a particle's mass or charge, and has units of angular momentum. It is  an observable, and the corresponding operator has a matrix representation with respect to a particular basis.