# Why do electrons have magnetic moments?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons

It's as simple as that. I understand they do have magnetic moments, but can't figure out why.

Comment: See [Spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Magnetic_moments)

Comment: "The "Dirac" magnetic moment, corresponding to tree-level Feynman diagrams (which can be thought of as the classical result), can be calculated from the Dirac equation. It is usually expressed in terms of the g-factor; the Dirac equation predicts g = 2 {\displaystyle g=2} {\displaystyle g=2} "  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_magnetic_dipole_moment

Comment: Don't expect someone to be able to answer this more definitively than "why do electrons have charge".

Comment: I like your answer more, Connor!

Comment: Why do electrons exist?

Comment: @my2cts why is do you give only 2 cents and not a bit more generous with the tips

Comment: I like this one. Because electrons have a property that might as well be called "tiny magnet". [MAGNETS: How Do They Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM)

Comment: [Why does the electron not spin](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/647867)